# Set column value based on join and self join MySql Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to set a column value in MySQL based on the following query.

```
select * from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.id = u.t1_id
and t2.status = 'verified'
and not exists (
    select 1 
    from table2 t2_2
    where t2.t1_id = t2_2.t1_id
    and t2_2.updated_at > t2.updated_at
)
```

This query returns the results I want, but when I try to add

```
SET t1.column_k = 'some value'
```

to the end, I'm getting an error that simply says `You've got a syntax error near set t1.column_k....` check manual corresponding to your version of `MySQL`.

I'd really like to know how to include a set on the results of this query and am having trouble formulating that.  Any help or ideas?

It's difficult and confusing to me I think because of the `self join`.  The eventual plan is to port this query w/the set command into a `migration file in rails` once I've got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `update`.  `Select` isn't used for setting values.

```
update table1 t1 join
       table2 t2
       on t1.id = u.t1_id and
          t2.status = 'verified' and
          not exists (select 1 
                      from table2 t2_2
                      where t2.t1_id = t2_2.t1_id and
                            t2_2.updated_at > t2.updated_at
                     ) 
    set t1.column_k = 'some value';
```